# Submitting custom post from frontend,jQuery ajax, and custom validation - can't find proper place to insert wp_insert_post()

Tags: custom-post-types, jquery, ajax, forms, wp-insert-post

I have three files: `submit.php` (a page), `validation.php`, `script.php`

I am trying to use the fields as a front end submission area via the `wp_insert_post()` function.

However, I don't know exactly where to put the function, as where I try either is before the `validation.php` file or if I put it in that file it causes an error since it can't pass wordpress functions.

I have tried playing with the `success` in the `$.ajax` but since the `die()` functions all result in it being successful can't trigger a create post.

Does anyone have a better solution?

In the `submit.php` I have a form:

```
<div class="" id="response"></div>
<form id="form_ticket_submit" method="post">
    <label for="form_ticket_subject">Subject of issue</label>
    <input id="form_ticket_subject" name="form_ticket_subject" type="text">
    <label for="form_ticket_content">Post</label>
    <textarea id="form_ticket_content" name="form_ticket_content"></textarea>
    <label for="form_ticket_tax_stage">Select Stage</label>
    <select id="form_ticket_tax_stage" name="form_ticket_tax_stage">
        <option value="">Select one</option>
        <?php foreach ($form_ticket_tax_cat_stage as $form_cat_stage) { echo '<option value="' . $form_cat_stage->slug . '">'. $form_cat_stage->name . '</option>'; } ?>
    </select>
    <input hidden="hidden" id="form_ticket_meta_date" name="form_ticket_meta_date" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo get_date_from_gmt( date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ), 'jS \of F, Y H:i:s' ); ?>">
    <input hidden="hidden" id="form_ticket_meta_user_name" name="form_ticket_meta_user_name" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $form_ticket_current_user_name; ?>">
    <input hidden="hidden" id="form_ticket_meta_user_email" name="form_ticket_meta_user_email" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $form_ticket_current_user_email; ?>">
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit Ticket" />
</form>
```

In the `script.js` I have:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#mb_ticket_submit").submit(function(a){
            a.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "validation.php",
                data: {
                    mb_ticket_subject:          $("#mb_ticket_subject").val(),
                    mb_ticket_content:          $("#mb_ticket_content").val(),
                    mb_ticket_tax_stage:        $("#mb_ticket_tax_stage option:selected").val(),
                    mb_ticket_tax_application:  $("#mb_ticket_tax_application option:selected").val(),
                    mb_ticket_meta_date:        $("#mb_ticket_meta_date").val(),
                    mb_ticket_meta_user_name:   $("#mb_ticket_meta_user_name").val(),
                    mb_ticket_meta_user_email:  $("#mb_ticket_meta_user_email").val(),
                },
                success: function(a){ $("div#response").show().html(a); },
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

Then finally the `validation.php` has the following (the $var are cleaned up, and validated from their `$_POST[]`:

```
    if( empty($form_ticket_meta_user_name) )  { die( 'Doesn\'t look like you have logged in properly'; ) }
    if( empty($form_ticket_meta_user_email) ) { die( 'Doesn\'t look like you have logged in properly'; ) }
    if( !empty($form_ticket_meta_user_email) ){ if( !filter_var($form_ticket_meta_user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) { die( 'Doesn\'t look like your email address is formatted properly. Contact your administrator.' ); } }
    if( empty($form_ticket_subject) ) { die( 'No subject' ); }
    if( empty($form_ticket_content) ) { die( 'No content' ); }
    if( empty($form_ticket_tax_stage) ) { die( 'No stage'); }
    if( empty($form_ticket_tax_application) ) { die( 'No app' ); }
    if( empty($form_ticket_tax_priority) ) { die( 'No priority' ); }
    if( empty($form_ticket_tax_location) ) { die( 'No location' ); }
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, I removed the URL from the `$.ajax`.

Next, I added the `validation.php` before the `<head>` section. That depends on how your theme is made (mine was placed before a `get_template_part()`)

Calling it here allows wordpress functions to be called, allowing the `wp_insert_post` to be called and utilised. Also, if you are making it completely notification forward, you can utilise the `wp_mail` after the post has been successful.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the goal through many ways. though the way you have selected is not an appropriate one but you can go with it also. just include the file wp-blog-header.php file (placed at the wordpress root) into validation.php above all other code. you can find all the wordpress related functions will work like a charm.

Comment: Please merge your two accounts.

Comment: How would you suggest I go about this? The above code was one I took from a previous theme I was making, where it would use the `$_POST` to form an email. So taking that, thats how I build to this. I originally had no external `validation.php` file, and before the head would `get_template_part()` which linked to the `wp_post_insert()`. Would you suggest I move everything back in there? Or how would you see it being improved?